# Looking to implement a timeline package in Angular 6

Tags: angular, d3.js, timeline

Using `npm install` in my Angular 6 project, I've installed this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-timelines

Problem is I don't understand how to import it into my Angular component.

We do have other `d3` imports already, so I'm just trying to play with this particular package.

Here's what we have :

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as d3 from 'd3-selection';
import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';
import * as d3Shape from 'd3-shape';
import * as d3Array from 'd3-array';
import * as d3Axis from 'd3-axis';
import * as d3TimeFormat from 'd3-time-format';
import * as d3Timeline from 'd3-timelines';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-timeline',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './timeline.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timeline.component.scss']
})
export class TimelineComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    title = 'Time Line';
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {    
       this.timelineCircle();
    }
    
      timelineCircle() {
        let width = 500; 
        var testData = [
            {times: [{"starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000}, {"starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}]},
            {times: [{"starting_time": 1355759910000, "ending_time": 1355761900000}, ]},
            {times: [{"starting_time": 1355761910000, "ending_time": 1355763910000}]}
          ];
          var chart = d3Timeline.timeline();
      }

}
```

The browser error I get is :

```
 ERROR TypeError: d3_timelines__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.timeline is not a function
```

I'm just not sure the proper way to import this package and use it within my component.

Advice is appreciated...

Comment: Without knowing the timeline package you are using, the error you are receiving is quite clear, property timeline from d3Timeline is not a function. Try logging the module first to see what is available. `console.log(d3Timeline)` inside your timelineCircle() method

Comment: Okay I will log. I assumed, however, that their `timeline()` function would be exposed via my var declaration `import * as d3Timeline from 'd3-timelines';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the function you're looking for is `d3Timeline.timelines()` (plural). The code snippet you have provided is timeline() singular.

I would also recommend matching the plurality on your module import:

```
import * as d3Timelines from 'd3-timelines';
...
var chart = d3Timelines.timelines()
```

I got the function's name from the package's examples folder: see line 102 (among others) in https://github.com/denisemauldin/d3-timeline/blob/master/examples/example.html

Comment: I also just noticed that they're exporting the `timelines` var at line 899 as `exports.timelines = timelines;`